# Laravel Notification or Mailable for friend request/accept

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mail, laravel-notification

Suppose that we have a social website that users can follow each other. Is it a better idea to use [Laravel Notification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications) to notify the user that someone wants to follow him or someone accepted his follow request or [Laravel Mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail) instead?

I have already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683957/laravel-5-3-notification-vs-mailable) and seems that Mailable is a better idea because the recipient and the email content is not the same (in the content I have to say that **$thisUserId** is requesting to follow you, or **$thisUserId** accepted your follow request.

What is the best way to implement this (*follow request*, *follow accepted*) or other actions such as *your friend commented on your post* or something like this?

**Laravel Notification** or **Laravel Mailable**?

Comment: you can use web notifications with pusher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you underestimate the **Laravel Notification**. It has also fliexibility to use the custom templates. And you can use `mailable` with this as well.

Follow the documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications

As friend request sent/accept comes under notification category and Laravel Notification just designed for the notificaiton purpose only. So no doubt you should go with this.

As it's provide the flexibility send notification on different channels as well along with `mail`.

The `mailable` is very limited to provide the reach mailing feature with laravel.

Rest all depends on your application architecture & your descision :)

Comment: As I'm writing this comment, I have solved my issue. The key concept I was missing, was the `__construct` method on my notification class which I could use to pass the recipient `user_id`. Definitely, the answer is to use notifications, not mailable.